# KVM Virtual Machine Webcam Permissions

Tags: usb, permissions, virtualization, webcam, kvm-virtualization

Host is Ubuntu 20.04, guest is Ubuntu 20.04.  I have added the host integrated webcam through the Virtual Machine Manager's "Add Hardware" button. An error message appears while attempting to start the VM: `libusb couldn't open USB device` `libusb requires write access to USB device nodes`. My webcam is at `/dev/bus/usb/001` and `ls -l` shows the device listed as `crw-rw-r-- 1 root root`. I am hoping someone can help me understand what that would be changed to (and how) in order to safely allow write access to the particular virtual machine (and nothing else)?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: use the terminal to go to the device directory `cd /dev/bus/usb/001` and attempt `chmod o+w <filename>` which will produce an error about the operation not being permitted, so then to modify the whole directory (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328825/chmod-changing-permissions-of-directory-operation-not-permitted#328830 ) to allow for that.  For me, this is too invasive from the defaults as I do not understand the implications on security. I don't have an approach for isolating the camera to only the virtual machine, either. So my answer is to avoid needing camera access with the virtual machine.